# php string replace without empty space

Tags: php

I'm using `str_replace` to remove some tags within a string, it's being replaced with just `''` but the line is still there, an empty line.  I tried to remove `\r\n` and variations of, and nothing will remove the empty line, without messing up other formatting.

Is there a way to replace an item in a string without leaving an empty line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `str_replace` with `trim`.

Answer (score 1):

Perform second replacement that removes empty lines